Incorrect username or password - jenkins master
I have provisioned a Jenkins server using Terraform on AWS as an AutoScalingGroup within an RHEL machine. For the credentials, I have used the resource "random_password" to generate a password for the Jenkins master instance and fed it into the server using an executable script generated from a template file. Here is how it's set up -
jenkins_master.sh
java -jar $jenkins_dir/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://127.0.0.1:8080/ -auth admin:$jenkins_admin_password install-plugin $plugin
template file config
data "template_file" "jenkinsmaster" {
  template = file("${path.module}/templates/jenkins_master.tpl")
  vars = {
    efs_dnsname            = aws_efs_file_system.jenkinsefs.dns_name
    jenkins_admin_password = local.jenkins_password
  }
}

locals.tf
jenkins_password            = var.jenkins_pwd == "" ? random_password.jenkins.result : var.jenkins_pwd
Everything runs fine till the point I attempt a login after port-forwarding and I get the error - "Incorrect username or password". I will edit and add more details as required.
I tried updating jenkins and java to their latest versions but that didn't help this issue.
